# Meteor on a Nitrous box: how to add a test record in the MongoDB database?

Tags: meteor, nitrousio

So, I have started to test Meteor on a Nitrous.io box in the cloud. I used to enter a test record by typing it directly into the Chrome browser console, like:

`Projects.insert({name:'First Project',client:'Project Central',duedate:new Date(),status:'On Hold'});`

However, that does not work on Nitrous. 
So, how do I add a test record in my meteor collection to work on?

Who can help me in the right direction? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you run `meteor run` in a Nitrous.io console,

open up another console and run `meteor mongo`.

Then you can type in a `db.Projects.insert(...)` or other mongoDB command.

Answer (score 0):

There might be the case if you removed `insecure` package, insert will not work from browser client.

Check if the 'insecure' package installed or not using following command

`meteor list --using`

which will list the packages which are used by the meteor app.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not the case. I just checked, and insecure is running OK!